# How to convert time to specific string?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I'm working  with a date that looks like this:

```
Mon Feb 04 2019 15:57:02 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

and I'm trying to convert it to this:

```
2019-02-04T15:57:02.000Z
```

but for some reason my code always adds **7 hours** and ends up being like this:

> "2019-02-05T22:57:02.000Z"

Can anyone tell me what I'm  doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

```
new Date(myTime as string).toISOString();
```

Comment: Running `new Date(string)` with any string that is not in ISO format, in UTC time, is asking for trouble. You're likely better off using something like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) with a specific format.

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you please provide an example? Thanks

Comment: From what you've written, you don't actually want the Z at the end then. That denotes UTC, which in this case, *is* 7 hours ahead of the time zone indicated.

Comment: Any ideas on how to prevent it from adding 7 hours?

Comment: "how to prevent it from adding 7 hours" --- there is no way to prevent it, you asked it to format it in UTC time - it did.

Comment: Subtract 7 hours from the result? :)

Comment: @progx there is no clean problem here, hence no clear solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is a decent date parsing and formatting library. To get what you're looking for, you'd use a statement like:

```js
console.log(moment
  .parseZone(
    "Mon Feb 04 2019 15:57:02 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)",
    "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss 'GMT'ZZ") // the format of the string presented
  .local()
  .format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')); // the format of the output
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I've broken the single line out into parts so it's a bit easier to read. A few notes:

- [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) allows you to parse the "-0700" from the string.
- [`local`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) converts the date from the parsed time zone to the current time zone
- [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) formats the date.

The [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) topic has a list of the formatting tokens used.
The [Parse > String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) topic lists the parsing tokens (which are the same as the formatting tokens for the most part).

Note that the output does not have a "Z" at the end; this is important because without the "Z", it is a local date. With the "Z" you are are actually specifying a date and time that is 7 hours earlier than the one you've been given.

Comment: Also add `Z` in the end, it would be a nonsense but that's what OP wants :shrug:

Comment: @progx I'm not even sure what to say about that. lodash is a library for manipulating arrays and objects. Moment.js is a library for parsing, manipulating, and displaying dates. Use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get this as a one-liner, but this is one way:

```
var time = new Date('Mon Feb 04 2019 15:57:02 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)')
new Date(time.setHours(time.getHours() + 7)).toISOString()

"2019-02-05T12:57:02.000Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not adding hours to the input date. What is happening is that your date string is using a particular timezone `GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)` and the time zone used in `new Date().toISOString()` is UTC `GMT+0000 (UTC)`. So when in the `Mountain Standard Time` timezone is `Mon Feb 04 2019 15:57:02`, in the `UTC` timezone is actually `2019-02-05T22:57:02.000Z`. There are your seven hours from `GMT-0700` to `GMT+0000`.

**EDITED**

If you don't really care about time zones and want to obtain 2019-02-04T15:57:02.000Z from Mon Feb 04 2019 15:57:02 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) you could just strip everything after GMT to let new Date() think it is an UTC date.

```
var timeString = 'Mon Feb 04 2019 15:57:02 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)';
new Date(timeString.substr(0, timeString.indexOf('GMT') + 3));

2019-02-04T15:57:02.000Z
```